# Turning list from text file into python list

Tags: python

I am teaching a class and I want them to read a list of 10 words from a text file and then randomly display 9 of them in a 3 by 3 grid.

My thoughts were as follows:

1) Read the text file using *readlist = open('N:\Words.txt', 'r')*

2) Python turns this into a list Python randomly chooses 9 using *import random*

3) Python diplays the list in a 3x3 grid

I have tried various things - readline, readlines, append characters - but with no or limited success.  I am missing something obvious but can't see it.

This adds the first word to the list, but how do I add the second word:

```
readlist = open('N:\Words.txt', 'r')
listwords=[]
firstword=readlist.read(5)
listwords.append(firstword)
print (listwords)
```

Comment: Could you show a bit more code, because this should be spot on. `readlines` is supposed to read the entire file in a list and then you can go `for line in file.readlines(): print(line)` easily. Of course in your case appending it to a list for processing is probably a better option. Strainght from the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects): `If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use list(f) or f.readlines().`

Comment: show your attempts and also an example.

Comment: do you have  a word per line?

Comment: Thanks @Michael9, I'm a Maths teacher who's been asked to teach Computer Science so need help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `random.sample` to get nine random words and split the list returned into three sublists:

```
from random import sample
from pprint import pprint as pp

with open("text.txt") as f:
    samp = sample(f.read().split(), 9)
    pp([samp[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(samp), 3)],width=40)

 [['seven', 'ten', 'four'],
 ['one', 'five', 'nine'],
 ['eight', 'two', 'six']]
```

text.txt:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

This will work if you have a word per line or a single line where the words are separated by whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm a Maths teacher who's been asked to teach Computer Science so need help!!

Comment: Padraic - it's a list of 10 lines with a 5 character word in each line - NIGHT,  SMOKE, GHOST

Comment: @UdayPatel,  so one word per line?

Comment: Yes, @Padraic Cunningham, sorry, one word per line not as I have written above.

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunningham, it works perfectly but please can you explain what is the significance of "width = 40"?

Comment: @UdayPatelm that is just to make it look nice using prettyprint, it makes the maximum width 40 so we get each sublist on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

`open` creates a file object.

Try this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
```

This is assuming the file has one word per line. `f.read()` returns the whole file as a string. string method `splitlines()` splits the string on newlines returning an array of strings with the newline stripped off.

I'm using a block here `with open(filename) as f:` so that the file will close immediately after you're reading with from it (once the block finishes). `words` is still in scope after the block is finished. This style just reads nicely and prevents the need to manually close the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

words = open('words.txt').read().splitlines()
shuffle(words)

chunks=[words[x:x+3] for x in xrange(0, 9, 3)]
for chunk in chunks:
    print chunk

['d', 'f', 'a']
['i', 'j', 'g']
['e', 'h', 'b']
```

words.txt contains all letters from a to j in a separate line each.

Comment: @igavrill.  Thank you.  It didn't work initially as it kept saying that chunk on the last line was a syntax error. However, when I changed 'xrange' to 'range' it seemed to like it.  Thank you for your help.